# What kind of flavour do Devil Fruits have?

Tags: one-piece

In the One Piece world, there are so many Devil Fruits having different shapes.
I'm a little bit curious about the flavour of Devil Fruits: Is it different from one to another?

If I'm not mistaken, there's a fruit that resembles Banana or Apple. Do they taste same as their real counterparts?

Is the taste of the Devil Fruits ever mentioned in the Anime or Manga?

Comment: Also in Chapter 744: After taking a bite of the Mera Mera no Mi, Sabo comments on how disgusting it tastes. So yeah it is disguisting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Devil fruits taste awful.

This is evidenced by the few occurences we've seen where a fruit has been eaten.

When Law eats his fruit (episode 706):
 [image: Law eating the Ope Ope no Mi]

And when Kaku eats Ushi Ushi no Mi Model: Giraffe and Kalifa eats the Awa Awa no Mi during the Water 7 Arc (Episode 271):

[image: Kaku and Kalifa saying "This Tastes Terrible!"]

During the same scene Jabra was trying to convince them not to eat it by saying that it tasted like crap:

[image: Jabra saying "It tastes like crap. Crap!"]

Based off the several examples of people eating it and saying it taste like crap I can definitely answer your question of how they taste with: Unlike their normal-fruit counterparts, they taste **awful**.

Comment: whoa ha! I don't remember all of this scenes, I guess I'm really need to rewatch the entire arcs. that mention above xD

Comment: @JTR Rewatching episode 1 is enough. Even Luffy commented on the horrible taste of the fruit.