# Does Devil Fruit taste bad?

Tags: one-piece

In One Piece, some people were shown eating the Devil Fruit such as Sabo and 2 CP9 said it was disgusting or tastes really bad. However, Luffy was shown eating it at the beginning without a complaint. In the anime series, he ate it for being upset; in a movie, he ate it for dessert. Another case was Buggy *the clown* but he doesn't stand much of an argument because he technically swallowed it whole by accident. Also with Chopper: he ate it when he was a deer. It it really tastes that bad, wouldn't he follow his instinct as an animal and stop eating it?

**TL;DR:** Does Devil Fruit taste bad?

Comment: even if Chopper animal instinct is to stop eating the fruit that taste so bad, he actually still get the power of DF, since we don't have to eat entire fruit to get the power from DF

Comment: and you can check my question [here](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/26826/what-kind-of-flavour-do-devil-fruits-have)

Comment: Chopper was outcast, solitary and hungy. His animal instinct told him to swallow whatever can keep him alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Devil Fruit tastes bad. It tastes so inexplicably bad that is akin to poison as stated in the wiki about [Devil Fruit](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Devil_Fruit).

Luffy has been shown in multiple different ways eating his Fruit in the manga, anime and movies. And also how he got his Fruit is different depending on the source.

The main point is that, in almost every case, a person eats the whole Fruit either piece by piece or by swallowing it whole.

Comment: They don't need to eat the whole fruit

Comment: That isn't the question.

Comment: If you mention it in your answer, then be correct.

Comment: If you have a more correct answer then post it.